# mysql : How can I only display the minimum values if there is more than 1 row with the same value

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

So I have some results where the query is like

```
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY birth_date ASC;
```

This simply puts the birth date in ascending order. I want to only display the elder most employees. How can I edit this query to display that

**Note** : More than 1 employee was born on the same day, therefore i have 6 users who are the eldest but how can I only display the eldest

Comment: add LIMIT - SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY birth_date ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: A caveat to the comment by @BerndBuffen. That will work, but with multiple eldest employees, which one gets returned each time is not guaranteed consistent.

Comment: @Uueerdo to garantthis you easy add the name at the end of the order by : **ORDER BY birth_date,Name_field ASC LIMIT 1;**

Comment: @BerndBuffen As long as name is unique among those people; as we know it isn't as a generalized rule. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with a subquery like:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE birth_date = (SELECT min(birth_date) FROM employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine solutions:

The LIMIT clause is used to specify the number of records to return.  Choose one and only SELECT rows with that birth_date.

```
SELECT * FROM employees where birth_date = (
SELECT birth_date FROM employees ORDER BY birth_date ASC LIMIT 1
);
```